# Graph API - Facebook - Business Page Tagged Messages, Get Comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a business page on Facebook. I want to see when someone tags my page on their feed in a public post. Further, I want to be able to see the comments that people make on that post. About 3 weeks ago I had no problem doing this. I could then use the Graph API and Graph Explorer to see the:

```
    /tagged?fields=message,from,created_time,likes,comments{from,message,created_time}
```

....a great deal of information.

Today when I try to access the likes or comments on the tagged post through Graph Explorer I get the greyed out text meaning "Field is empty or disallowed with my access token." However, I have the page access token via Graph Explorer. Can anyone help me with this? Did Facebook change something?

This is not the same as the linked post. I have tested it with all user and extended permissions enabled. I am not trying to see a list of my friends, I am trying to see the name and comment of a friend of someone that tagged my page. The code I posted above worked fine less than a month ago, which was still Graph v2.5.

[Each of these has likes and comments yet the API won't allow access.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyBBp.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

Comment: I can get access to my own comments on a post if I go through me/accounts/tagged{comments}, but I am still unable to see other people's even with the user_posts permission.

Comment: Are you definitely using the same page access token as the page-id that you are retrieving posts for? I tried your request using a page access token hitting https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/page-id/tagged?fields=message,from,created_time,likes,comments{from,message,created_time} which worked as expected

Comment: @Hey Darren Yes. See above. The page id and token are for that page.